# SQL Server: Generate unique customer key based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on cleaning up a customer list from an ecommerce site. The customer list has a many to many relationship between customer ID and customer email. For example, a customer could place an order with the same email while logged in or anonymous, and the result would be two customer records with the same email but different customer IDs. Similarly, a customer could create orders with two different emails while logged in which would result in customer records with the same ID but different emails. Given this, I want to create a list of customers with truly unique IDs based on either email or customer number. In addition, there are situations where the email is blank, so customers records that both have blank emails but different IDs would need to be considered two different customers.

So given something like this:

```
CUST_ID CUST_EMAIL
------------------------
123     test1@gmail.com
123     test2@gmail.com
124     test3@gmail.com
125     test3@gmail.com
126
127
128     test4@gmail.com
128     test5@gmail.com
129     test4@gmail.com
```

I would want to generate a key like this:

```
CUST_ID CUST_EMAIL      NEW_CUST_KEY
------------------------------------
123     test1@gmail.com     1
123     test2@gmail.com     1
124     test3@gmail.com     2
125     test3@gmail.com     2
126                         3
127                         4
128     test4@gmail.com     5
128     test5@gmail.com     5
129     test4@gmail.com     5
```

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion or something reproducible without changing the existing data? I assume conversion, based on the first sentence, so why not do this in a `WHILE` loop. Then you can compare against the previous record to see if you need a new ID.

Comment: I will need to run this on a daily basis to incorporate new customer records, but it doesn't matter if the generated key for a given customer changes from day to day as long as the records are grouped correctly. I will most likely just trunc and reload the destination table each day, so anything that works as a one time conversion should be fine.

Comment: As far as the WHILE loop is concerned, I don't think comparing against just the previous record would work. If you look at the last record in the example above, if you compared it with the record before, it would seem like it needs a new key (different email and ID). However, it does share an email with the row two previous, which would mean all three should be grouped as a single customer with the same new key.

Comment: Instead of the previous row, you could query your "destination" table to see if it has already been created for that email. In this case, you definitely need to loop in CUST_ID order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLDTABLE - is your table 
NEWTABLE - will have result

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #NEWTABLE
(
    NEW_CUST_KEY int not null ,
    CUST_ID int not null, 
    CUST_EMAIL nvarchar(100) null   
)
------------------------------------
insert into #NEWTABLE (NEW_CUST_KEY,CUST_ID,CUST_EMAIL)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL) AS NEW_CUST_KEY, CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL 
FROM
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL
    FROM OLDTABLE 
    GROUP BY CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL
) T


UPDATE Upd SET NEW_CUST_KEY = T.NEW_CUST_KEY
FROM #NEWTABLE Upd
join (
    SELECT CUST_ID, min(NEW_CUST_KEY) AS NEW_CUST_KEY 
    FROM #NEWTABLE 
    GROUP BY CUST_ID) T
on Upd.CUST_ID = T.CUST_ID

UPDATE Upd SET NEW_CUST_KEY = T.NEW_CUST_KEY
FROM #NEWTABLE Upd
join (
    SELECT CUST_EMAIL, min(NEW_CUST_KEY) AS NEW_CUST_KEY 
    FROM #NEWTABLE 
    GROUP BY CUST_EMAIL) T    
on nullif(Upd.CUST_EMAIL,'') = nullif(T.CUST_EMAIL,'')    

UPDATE Upd SET NEW_CUST_KEY = T.CHANGE_CUST_KEY
FROM #NEWTABLE Upd
join (
    SELECT NEW_CUST_KEY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEW_CUST_KEY) AS CHANGE_CUST_KEY
    FROM #NEWTABLE 
    GROUP BY NEW_CUST_KEY) T
on Upd.NEW_CUST_KEY = T.NEW_CUST_KEY

select * from #NEWTABLE
```

Comment: I forgot about empty Email. Chanhed one line on :

on nullif(Upd.CUST_EMAIL,'') = nullif(T.CUST_EMAIL,'')

Comment: upd: changed picture in answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use row_number.....
Something like this......

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL) AS New_Cust_Key
FROM YOUR TABLES
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER here would just output 1 for every row, as you are partitioning by both CUST_ID and CUST_EMAIL and that is already a distinct list.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to map your users with their IDs to their emails and vice-versa and as a result I created this Frankenstein monster query:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE
(
  CUST_ID INT
  , CUST_EMAIL VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @Customers (CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL)
VALUES (123, 'test1@gmail.com')
  , (123, 'test2@gmail.com')
  , (124, 'test3@gmail.com')
  , (125, 'test3@gmail.com')
  , (126, '')
  , (127, '')
  , (128, 'test4@gmail.com')
  , (128, 'test5@gmail.com')
  , (129, 'test4@gmail.com');


SELECT DISTINCT C.CUST_ID
  , C.CUST_EMAIL
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY T.CUST_ID) AS NEW_CUST_KEY
FROM @Customers AS C
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_EMAIL
  FROM @Customers
  EXCEPT
  SELECT C2.CUST_ID, C2.CUST_EMAIL
  FROM @Customers AS C1
  INNER JOIN @Customers AS C2
    ON C2.CUST_EMAIL = C1.CUST_EMAIL
    AND C2.CUST_ID > C1.CUST_ID
    AND C1.CUST_EMAIL <> ''
  ) AS T
  ON CASE
    WHEN (T.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND T.CUST_EMAIL = C.CUST_EMAIL AND T.CUST_EMAIL = '') THEN 1
    WHEN (T.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID OR T.CUST_EMAIL = C.CUST_EMAIL) AND T.CUST_EMAIL <> '' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END = 1;
```

Using your test data it produced exactly this, it does seem to match your expectations:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ CUST_ID ║   CUST_EMAIL    ║ NEW_CUST_KEY  ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║     123 ║ test1@gmail.com ║             1 ║
║     123 ║ test2@gmail.com ║             1 ║
║     124 ║ test3@gmail.com ║             2 ║
║     125 ║ test3@gmail.com ║             2 ║
║     126 ║                 ║             3 ║
║     127 ║                 ║             4 ║
║     128 ║ test4@gmail.com ║             5 ║
║     128 ║ test5@gmail.com ║             5 ║
║     129 ║ test4@gmail.com ║             5 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

You can see this in real life on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/390233/generating-new-ids)

Let me know if this works in your actual DB.

Comment: I am newby here. Thank you for link to data.stackexchange.com. Very useful resource. @Evaldas

Comment: @evaldas Is there a way to solve this if the user if the column cust_id is replaced with mobile numbers?